# #1411 - Incorrect datetime value for function str_to_date on INSERT INTO...SELECT

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime, select, insert

These queries require the string to date conversion because Timestamp is stored as a string, and the logging application is unchangeable.

I have a select query that works perfectly ->

```
(SELECT main.user_id, main.Timestamp
FROM `user_table` main
WHERE STR_To_DATE( main.Timestamp , '%a %b %d %H:%i:%s CST %Y' ) <
  (SELECT  MAX(STR_To_DATE( sub.Timestamp , '%a %b %d %H:%i:%s CST %Y' )) 
   FROM `user_table` sub
   WHERE sub.user_id = main.user_id ))
```

This will select ALL BUT most recently added user id and timestamp from my table.

However, when I try to insert this into another table...like so ->

```
INSERT INTO user_table_temp (`user_id`, `Timestamp`)
(SELECT main.user_id, main.Timestamp
FROM `user_table` main
WHERE STR_To_DATE( main.Timestamp , '%a %b %d %H:%i:%s CST %Y' ) <
  (SELECT  MAX(STR_To_DATE( sub.Timestamp , '%a %b %d %H:%i:%s CST %Y' )) 
   FROM `user_table` sub
   WHERE sub.user_id = main.user_id ))
```

I get the following error ->

```
#1411 - Incorrect datetime value: 'Mon Mar 14 16:10:10 CDT 2011' for function str_to_date
```

The reason for this is because my Timestamps are stored in two formats. One will store as 'CST' during non-daylight-savings time, the other will store as 'CDT' during daylight-savings time. When the INSERT INTO SELECT gets to the first row that has the opposite of what I'm querying against, it will fail with the above message.

I have also tried to COALESCE them, which also works when just running the select ->

```
INSERT INTO user_table_temp  (`user_id `, `Timestamp`)
(SELECT main.user_id , main.Timestamp
FROM `user_table` main
WHERE COALESCE(STR_To_DATE( main.Timestamp , '%a %b %d %H:%i:%s CDT %Y' ), STR_To_DATE( main.Timestamp , '%a %b %d %H:%i:%s CST %Y' )) <
  (SELECT  MAX(COALESCE(STR_To_DATE( sub.Timestamp , '%a %b %d %H:%i:%s CDT %Y' ), STR_To_DATE( sub.Timestamp , '%a %b %d %H:%i:%s CST %Y' ))) 
   FROM `user_table` sub
   WHERE sub.user_id = main.user_id ))
```

Why would this fail on an INSERT, but the SELECT would work?

Comment: Try a `CAST(STR_TO_DATE(...) AS DATETIME)` and see what happens.

Comment: @hacket I think this is stupid, but in sql-server will give an error. Have you tried to do the insert without the () ? I mean, insert into fields select from.. If that works, I will put it as an answer

Comment: @ElVieejo Just tried it, and I get the same error. Is this possibly a MySQL bug?

Comment: @hacket Did you get an error or a warning?

Comment: @Devart I'm not sure, I'll need to run it again. Is there a difference?

Comment: The error may abort script execution, the warning - is just an information and may say that something is wrong. Warnings can be checked with `SHOW WARNINGS` query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it fails on INSERT because you're not using [a supported format](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-literals.html). The supported formats . . .

> As a string in either 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS' or 'YY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS'
>   format. A “relaxed” syntax is permitted here, too: Any punctuation
>   character may be used as the delimiter between date parts or time
>   parts. For example, '2012-12-31 11:30:45', '2012^12^31 11+30+45',
>   '2012/12/31 11*30*45', and '2012@12@31 11^30^45' are equivalent.
>
> As a string with no delimiters in either 'YYYYMMDDHHMMSS' or
>   'YYMMDDHHMMSS' format, provided that the string makes sense as a date.
>   For example, '20070523091528' and '070523091528' are interpreted as
>   '2007-05-23 09:15:28', but '071122129015' is illegal (it has a
>   nonsensical minute part) and becomes '0000-00-00 00:00:00'.
>
> As a number in either YYYYMMDDHHMMSS or YYMMDDHHMMSS format, provided
>   that the number makes sense as a date. For example, 19830905132800 and
>   830905132800 are interpreted as '1983-09-05 13:28:00'.

Comment: I'm not really following your answer...do you mean because the format has the CST and CDT in it?

Comment: @hacket: Yes. And it has 'Mon' in it, too. Neither of those appear in the supported formats.

Comment: This is the only thing that makes sense to me. Whatever I do, it will not work. We are just going to use Excel to get rid of the duplicates, as crude as that is...