# STR_TO_DATE incorrect datetime mysql

Tags: mysql, datetime, str-to-date

I have tried to search many questions about this.. But it seems telling solutions about *Quotes* use.

*references* : [**1**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12198332/1411-incorrect-datetime-value-for-function-str-to-date-on-insert-into-selec), [**2**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37824483/error-code-1411-incorrect-datetime-value-0000-00-00-for-function-str-to-dat), [**3**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31789072/warning-code-1411-incorrect-datetime-value), [**4**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14961490/mysql-error-code-1411-incorrect-datetime-value-for-function-str-to-date)

In my case,

```
select STR_TO_DATE('17-08-2016 11:30:51 AM','%d/%m/%Y %h:%i:%s %p');
```

gives output `NULL`.
And In `INSERT` statement:

```
INSERT INTO BILLING(BILL_NUMBER,BILLING_DATE)
VALUES ('1',STR_TO_DATE('17-08-2016 11:30:51 AM','%d/%m/%Y %h:%i:%s %p'));
```

It throws Error :

> Error Code: 1411. Incorrect datetime value: '17-08-2016 11:30:51 AM'
>   for function str_to_date

NOTE: 1. Date format is fixed > `'%d/%m/%Y %h:%i:%s %p'`
    2.   And String format is also fixed > `'17-08-2016 11:30:51 AM'` which I am capturing from C# Service.

Thanks In Advance!

Comment: replace `/` by hyphen. `select STR_TO_DATE('17-08-2016 11:30:51 AM','%d-%m-%Y %h:%i:%s %p');`

Comment: the date format, I m getting is through service. So can't change it

Comment: I asked to change the format not the date. Look carefully

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Format does not match the string. Change the slashes to  -

```
select STR_TO_DATE('17-08-2016 11:30:51 AM','%d-%m-%Y %h:%i:%s %p');
```

Answer (score 0):

As Date from Service itself was coming wrong. So, service needs to be changed:

Previously was passing `billObj.BillingDate` of type `string`.

It changed to:

```
billObj.BillingDate = (DateTime.ParseExact(billObj.BillingDate, HotelApplication.AppCode.BusinessLayer.util.StaticDefinitions.appDateFormat, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)).ToString();
```

And it worked out :) Thanks for all helps!